# How to get item name in pandas panel.apply function

Tags: python, pandas, panel

Assume panel1 is pandas panel I have, which contains two dataframes df1 and df2 with name 'item1' and 'item2'. By this code,

```
panel1.apply(lambda x: func(x) , axis = [1,2])
```

I can pass each item, which is a single dataframe, as x to func(x), and do some operations in the function. However, how can I know the item name of x in the function? For example, code is like this

```
def func(x):
    print x.itemname  #obviously this cannot work.
```

I don't want to use for loop like this because it is very time consuming,

```
for item in panel1.items:
    panel1[item] = 'some calculations'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you iterate over the panel's dataframes? You say you're worried about the speed of a loop, but I don't think it has to be slow. For example,

```
mypanel = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2, 5, 4), items=['Item1', 'Item2'],
                  major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5),
                  minor_axis=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

def func1(k, x):
    print(k)
    return x.apply(np.log)

mypanel.apply(lambda x: func1('the wrong name', x))  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
pd.Panel({k: func1(k, v) for k, v in mypanel.iteritems()})  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 800 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `apply`, the speed difference is minimal; you should feel free to use `iteritems`.

The speed *is* materially different if you're using a vectorized function such as `panel.mean()`. But it looks like you're not doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I am focusing on a single dataframe, and want to use function to do calculations to each column, is iteritems() also better than apply(lambda x)?

Comment: I think the point is that the vectorised functions often use a much faster C implementation. If you're applying a pure Python function then it doesn't matter much either way.

Comment: @SimonBeckham - they are very similar from a pandas POV I think - it's just whatever you think is cleaner. For me, `apply` is cleaner, but you don't get the name.